# iPad landscape + portrait view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

How can I have my view maintain it's dimensions without altering any of the old xib elements. I have a view in portrait that has a scroll view 3/4 of the page, and 1/4 at the bottom a text view. When using this in a split view in landscape, I don't get to see the bottom text. How can I get to see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your view's `autoresizingMask` settings. If you're using xib files, look at the Inspector window (in Interface Builder) and select the Size tab (ruler icon). From there you'll notice the Autosizing section and should be able to alter the settings.